# Roth 401(k) Contribution Limits

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, retirement

Please consider an individual, in the US, who has net earnings from self employment of $8000 who wishes to contribute to a Roth 401(k) plan. For
tax purposes these earnings can be reduced by 20% due to the new tax law.

How much money can be put into his Roth 401(k) plan? Under the old rules it
would be $8000 but now, I am wondering if it is $8000 or $6400?

Comment: If this person is self-employed, how do they have a Roth 401k, which is an employer-sponsored plan?

Comment: There are brokerage firms that will enable a self employed person have a Roth 401(k). I have mine through E*Trade.

Comment: Why not ask the administrator of your Solo 401(k) plan? The answer depends on your specific plan.

Comment: I did. They said they did not know.

Answer (score -1):

Roth 401(k) plan contribution comes after tax deduction of the particular employee.The limit for employee contribution is $18,500 per year for age under 50 years and $24,500 per year for age 50 years and above.This limit can be combination of total of Traditional 401(k) and Roth 401(k).Maximum Total contribution from employee and employer must be less than 100% of employees salary or $55,000 for age under 50 and $66,000 for age 50 and above.Based on these rules you can contribute to Roth 401(k) plan.

Comment: I agree that this person can put money into his Roth 401(K). The question is, how much?